# Linear layout doesn't wrap content

Tags: android

I wanted to create a Linear Layout with images in it. I added pictures to it but it doesn't wrap height to content. Here is my code:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And here is output:

[image: Linear Layout]

As You can see above and below each image is free space. The picture is a square so it should be aligned to the top edge without any free space. What can I do to avoid this margin?

Comment: Try setting "adjustViewBounds" to true in every ImageView

Comment: @Iscle It works! I have done it before I posted this question but I just set `adjustViewBounds` to one `ImageView` and it had bounds like any other so I thought it didn't work. But When I set it to all it works. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! It's a trap for young players :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Iscle. To make it work I had to set `adjustViewBounds="true"` on every `ImageView`. Setting it on once doesn't show any effects. Every view in Linear Layout must have this property set on true

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `android:scaleType` to your `ImageView`'s and set it to `center` or `centerCrop` according to your needs.

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: I tried this but when I set to `centerCrop` or `center` my image just get cropped on the right and left. [It looks like this](https://imgur.com/89IGkVz). But as @Iscle wrote in comment, setting to all images `adjustViewBounds="true"` works

Comment: @iknow please post it as an answer so it can help some one in the future

Comment: is it okey to post someone comment as an own answer?